# What is the difference between "Nautilus", "Files"  and  "Home Folder"?

Tags: nautilus, icons, home-directory, hud

When I type "nau" in the search bar of the applications-HUD the result is a "Home Folder" folder and a "Files" folder installed but the "Files" has a Home drawing in it and is recently used, whereas the "Files" doesn't and is not recently used. The search result also returns some tools for Nautilus but with different icons and I can't see any nautilus in the HUD. Where is this guy Nautilus and how is its face?. This is puzzling!. I can't find Nautilus!. In addition, When I select the folders "Files" and "Home Folder" I can see no difference between the windows dispalyed  for "Home Folder" (without Home) and the "Files Folder" (with a Home), and none of them is the real "home" folder where all the users have their files!!.
I would rather have everything in Chinese, ha ha.

Comment: It looks like you are referring to dash instead of HUD. Here is the name of the things: http://complete-concrete-concise.com/ubuntu-2/ubuntu-12-04/ubuntu-12-04-basic-unity-interface-desktop-tutorial

Comment: Yes, thanks for the corection and the link which is a very good site

Answer (score 2):

Nautilus is your graphical file browser. "Files" and "Home" in the HUD both launch Nautilus in my Home folder in 12.04. Don't remember this behavior in 11.10, but then I never paid much attention to it in the HUD instead preferring to launch it from the Launcher or a command line.

No matter how you launch it, it's still Nautilus the file browser. Much like Windows Explorer (not internet explorer) was the file browser for Windows whether you launched Explorer or clicked Computer in the menu. To verify it's still the same Nautilus no matter how you launch it, just Click **HELP** and select **ABOUT**.

Once you launch Nautilus which ever way you prefer, you can always revert to the entire File System by clicking **File System** in the Computer menu along the left.

Comment: Well, thank you. This is very puzzling because if I have another file manager (or more), both will be called "Home Folder" and "Files"? How do you distinguish?. Do you know if it is possible to have the "Files" folder without a home in it, the "Home" folder with a home in it and with the name of the user, of course, and the Nautilus application with its place with its own icon? Everything in its place and with its name. I mean... not only for me but for new and normal users that want normal and clear things.

Comment: I think the thinking is that it's because it's view belongs to a user. If you open a terminal, then type `gksu nautilus` then it will open to the Home of the Sudo user. Naturally, you can open a terminal and open nautilus as you, and you can even do it in any directory you want. For instance, if you want to open the root as you type `nautilus /`.

Answer (score 0):

Just about the icons - 
There are 3 .desktops installed by default concerning nautilus. They have a 'display' name & an actual file name

'Files' - `nautilus.desktop`, used by gnome-shell, Classic sessions (will show as recently used when browsing nautilus as root

'Files' - `nautilus-folder-handler.desktop`, is included for users upgrading from pre 11.10 or otherwise there would be some issues

'Home Folder' - `nautilus-home.desktop`, used by unity sessions, doesn't use the icon with the 'home' in it because it was felt that would confuse users

Comment: Well, what is obviously confusing is the way it is done, and what would be clear order would be the opposite: the things with their own names and their own icons (no need even to copy the idea from MacOS). Thank you for your answer. Now the problem is how to change everything to put order and clarity, which should be the default: the home folder with the home, the files folder with the files folder and/or the nautilus app with the nautilus icon. Is that possible?

Comment: Unfortunately I think you're missing the point. maybe re-read James answer again. If you want to have "Home Folder" use an icon with the home on it that's ok, I do that here. If you also want  "Files"  be a plain folder icon you can do so if inclined. Other than that it really doesn't matter, clicking on either icon in the Dash achieves the same thing - opens nautilus At your home folder location

Comment: Unfortunately I had to change and use an icon=system-file-manager and name="my home" for the nautilus-home.desktop that should be called home.desktop or my_home.desktop and change the nautilus.desktop to have the icon=nautilus and the name=Nautilus. As I told you, the opposite of what it is makes things to have their own name and their own icon. So, after the change things are ok, I hope I could upload a screenshot, an image is worth more than 1000 words, hehe.

Comment: The only thing I haven't been able to do and I would like to know how to do is to use an item type application for the Nautilus application ONLY and an Item folder for any folder in the launcher, that should be opened with nautilus, and should show its contents with right-click. Because one thing is an application and another one a folder. That is the reason you have a mess and duplicates everywhere.