# non-search file picking with keyboard?

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, files, usability

When using "Files" (the default gnome file manager application) I cannot use the keyboard to select a file that i know is already in the current view.

Only way to use the keyboard is to clumsily press the arrow keys repeatedly.

If I try to type the first characters of the filename, as I do in every single other filemanager under the sun, Files insists on starting a different feature: full text search.

How can i stop it from starting full text search? it is not a feature I want. Hiding the other files (context) and showing files that have absolutely nothing of the characters i'm typing in the name (since it also searches in the content!) confuses me a lot.

My current workaround is to use tunar. But this causes a whole other sort of issues and some software is hardcoded in bringing up Files. So i'd much like to fix Files itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try **Nautilus Typeahead Search** as described in this article:
[How to Enable Nautilus Typeahead Search in Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/enable-nautilus-type-ahead-in-ubuntu)

After installing the [patched Nautilus files](https://github.com/lubomir-brindza/nautilus-typeahead) from the PPA, the suggested `nautilus -r` command to refresh Nautilus did not work for me ("`Unknown option -r`"), but type-ahead search worked as expected after a reboot.

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS running Nautilus 3.36.3, where ["Files" is "Nautilus" underneath](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131075/what-is-the-difference-between-nautilus-files-and-home-folder).

Comment: Thanks. For others in the future, this answer summary is "use ArchLinux package as they fight against ubuntu/gnome bad design decisions". Let's see how long they can keep it up. For now, I moved to KDE